# AWK negative regular expression with variable

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I am using awk in a bash script to compare two files to get just the not-matching lines.
I need to compare all three fields of the second file (as one pattern?) with all lines of the first file:

First file:

```
chr1    9997    10330   HumanGM18558_peak_1     150     .       10.78887        18.86368        15.08777        100
chr1    628885  635117  HumanGM18558_peak_2     2509    .       83.77238        255.95094       250.99944       5270
chr1    15966215        15966638        HumanGM18558_peak_3    81      .       7.61567 11.78841        8.17169 200
```

Second file:

```
chr1 628885 635117
chr1 1250086 1250413
chr1 16613629 16613934
chr1 16644496 16644800
chr1 16895871 16896489
chr1 16905126 16905616
```

The current idea is to load one file in an array and use AWKs negative regular expression to compare.

```
readarray a < file2.txt
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
awk -v var="$i" '!/var/' file1.narrowPeak | cat > output.narrowPeak
done
```

The problem is that `'!/var/'` is not working with variables.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: on closer look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script, there's only one comment on how to use variables as regexp and not a hint for negative regexp in that question.. `$0 !~ var` is what you are looking for based on question title, but there's far better solution using just awk instead of bash+awk

Comment: Why not `grep -v "$i"`

Comment: Also using shell loop to process text is bad idea. Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Piping to `cat` is a new [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) on me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk` alone:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3]; next} !(($1,$2,$3) in a)' file2 file1
chr1    9997    10330   HumanGM18558_peak_1     150     .       10.78887        18.86368        15.08777        100
chr1    15966215        15966638        HumanGM18558_peak_3    81      .       7.61567 11.78841        8.17169 200
```

- `NR==FNR` this will be true only for the first file, which is `file2` in this example
- `a[$1,$2,$3]` create keys based on first three fields, if spacing is exactly same between the two files, you can simply use `$0` instead of `$1,$2,$3`
- `next` to skip remaining commands and process next line of input
- `($1,$2,$3) in a` to check if first three fields of `file1` is present as key in array `a`. Then invert the condition.

Here's another way to write it (thanks to Ed Morton)

```
awk '{key=$1 FS $2 FS $3} NR==FNR{a[key]; next} !(key in a)' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 3):

When the pattern is stored in a variable, you have to use the match operator:

```
awk -v var="something" '
  $0 !~ var {print "this line does not match the pattern"}
'
```

---

With this problem, regular expression matching looks a bit awkward. I'd go with Sundeep's solution, but if you really want regex:

```sh
awk '
  NR == FNR {
    # construct and store the regex
    patt["^" $1 "[[:blank:]]+" $2 "[[:blank:]]+" $3 + "[[:blank:]]"] = 1
    next
  }
  {
    for (p in patt)
      if ($0 ~ p)
        next
    print
  }
' second first
```

Comment: That 2nd script would be clearer if you replaced `patt` and `p` with `regexps` and `r` since there are no `patterns` in text matching, just `regexps` or `strings`. You need a `"$"` at the end of each regexp where you populate the array to avoid false matches. You don't need the `= 1`.

Comment: Right, but not `$`, I'd want a space (or some separator character).

Comment: I like to have an assignment there, personal style. Agree to disagree about use of "pattern".

Comment: Fair enough. For me seeing code that says `pattern` is like applying for a job cleaning cages at the zoo and all they'll tell you is you'll be in the cage with `animals`. Personally I'd like to know if it'll be rabbits or tigers but YMMV I suppose :-).